# Python: Getting the resolution of the media in a gstreamer pipeline

Tags: python, gstreamer

As the title suggests, I need a way to get the resolution of the media running in the Gstreamer pipeline. I know it has something to do with the caps in the pipeline. But how do I access it?
Also, let's say I somehow got it and it is of the type Gst.caps, how do I get the actual width and height from this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If running your pipeline by gst-launch-1.0, you can actually see the caps negotiation by putting GST_DEBUG=7 before gst-launch-1.0.  However, GST_DEBUG=5 may get you the information you need without the huge amount of trace information given by GST_DEBUG=7.